# How do I add a conditional stylesheet for blackberry curve?

Tags: blackberry, mobile, css

Any way to insert a *conditional style-sheet* for **'Blackberry curve 2007'** or a simple redirect detecting that device and calling a different `.html` page? I want to gracefully degrade my site for a really simple version in blackberry curve 2007, but have it remain the same but just responsive in iPhone & Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if CSS supports conditional includes, but if your backend webserver is running PHP, ASP, JSP, CGI/Perl, or other kind of scriptable environment, then you can simply read and parse the `User-Agent` header that the Curve webbrower sends to the server, and then have your server code either issue an HTTP redirect or dynamically generate suitable HTML as needed.